# How to make a sticky sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and trying to figure out how to make a sticky sidebar. I am trying to use affix but I can't seem to get it working right.

on jsfiddel example, I want the 'Aside' to stay fixed on the right once you scroll passed the header. I have looked at other examples and tried loads of different things but cant get it to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmg7mo5f/2/

Am I doing something wrong with this:

```
   <aside class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="82">
```

FYI: 82px is the height of my actual header

Comment: In your fiddle you missed jQuery library, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/x54nfLLq/

Comment: Thanks, I updated it there... http://jsfiddle.net/rmg7mo5f/3/. It still jumps down - I don't want it to move until you scroll passed the header and then it should move down-with no space at the top

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy Please do not make minor edits like this. Tags should not be in the question titles.

Comment: This example should help: http://www.bootply.com/100983 -- Make sure you include the CSS for `.affix`